# Marking Field As Invalid When Username Exist In Database jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validation Plugin to check to see if the fields on a register form are valid. As it is right now if the #reg_username field is less then 4 characters the form will not submit. I am already doing an ajax request to check my database for the username and if the username exist it is setting the response to 1 and if there is not a user it is setting it to 0. If there a way that i can use that information in the validate function to set the field to invalid if response is 1. So the form will not submit if the username matches one in the database. I dont know if you need more code but if let let me know.

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});

$( "#reg_form" ).validate({
  rules: {
    reg_username: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 4
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `remote` rule as described here http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method
The remote rule will fire last, so a server call will only be done if your other client side rules are ok (required, minlength).